# IndentationError: expected an indented block cannot loop script

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am trying to make a loop so that the script generates hash constantly

```
from bitcoin import *
import os
import hashlib
import base58

while True:
    priv =  random_key()
    pubkey = privtopub(priv)
    compress_pubkey = False
    
 
    if (compress_pubkey):
    if (ord(pubkey[-2:].decode('hex')) % 2 == 0):
        pubkey_compressed = '02'
    else:
        pubkey_compressed = '03'
    pubkey_compressed += pubkey[2:66]
    hex_str = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey_compressed)
    else:
        hex_str = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey)
 
key_hash = hash160(hex_str)
```

I am using Python 3 and I am getting the error:

```
    if (ord(pubkey[-2:].decode('hex')) % 2 == 0):
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: TL:DR Select this if and the line below and press TAB on your keyboard.
Python needs indentation for code inside an if block

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because first `if` statement does not have anything in it, you can use `pass` keyword to remove an error or remove the if statement if you don't need it(see comments in code)

```py
from bitcoin import *
import os
import hashlib
import base58

while True:
    priv =  random_key()
    pubkey = privtopub(priv)
    compress_pubkey = False
    
 
    if (compress_pubkey): #error
        pass #add something hereor add pass keyword to remove error
    if (ord(pubkey[-2:].decode('hex')) % 2 == 0):
        pubkey_compressed = '02'
    else:
        pubkey_compressed = '03'
        hex_str = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey) # you can't have more than one else
    pubkey_compressed += pubkey[2:66]
    hex_str = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey_compressed)
 
key_hash = hash160(hex_str)
```

Comment: Now I am getting the error: else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you have 2 `else` statements in a single if look carefully in the solution I've combined your both else into one, as that was a syntax error.

Comment: I am getting the error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Writes that this is not true: if (ord (pubkey [-2:]. Decode ('hex'))% 2 == 0):